# Instead of printing, returning the value of whole the string instead

Tags: python

Currently working on an assignment where I want to print stars as triangles, the code is currently looking like this (very basic, I know):

```
def triangelbasupp(n,m):
    for a in range(0,m):
        print((n*" "),(m*"*"))
        m=m-2
        n=n+1
        if m<=0:
            break
```

When I enter, for example (3,1) I will get first 3 stars in the first row, then 1 star. This code is working fine, the problem is that for the assignment, I want to ONLY return the whole string that constitutes the triangle, it also has to contain the '\n' for switching row. Does anyone have a clue how I can do this?

Comment: Try to append all your sting values in a single string alongwith "\n", wherever required and at last print that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of printing, initialize an  empty string and use the string concatenation operator to build the string:

```
def triangelbasupp(n,m):
    s = ""
    for a in range(0,m):
        s += n*" " + m*"*" + "\n"
        m=m-2
        n=n+1
        if m<=0:
            break
    return s
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) one of the answers

Answer (score 2):

Collect the lines in a list, then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them with `\n` and return.

```
def triangelbasupp(n,m):
    lines = []
    for a in range(0,m):
        lines.append(n*" " + m*"*")
        ...
    return "\n".join(lines)
```

Or shorter:

```
def triangelbasupp(n, m):
    return "\n".join(("*"*i).center(n) for i in range(m, 0, -2))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time, I really appreciate it!